# Differentiable extension of $f(x)-g(x)=e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are **positive** functions defined on $(0, \infty)$ such that
$$
f(x) - g(x)  = e^x \quad \forall x \in (0, \infty).
$$
Moreover, assume that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are **differentiable arbitrarily often** on $(0 ,\infty)$.

Do there exist extensions of $f$ and $g$, denoted by $F$ and $G$, such that
$$
F(x) - G(x) = e^x \quad \forall x \in (0 - \delta, \infty)
$$
for some $\delta>0$, and such that both $F$ and $G$ are differentiable? Clearly, if one of them is differentiable, then so should be the other.

Comment: Do you really want $G(x) - F(x)$, or should that be $F(x)-G(x)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the remark. I just edited.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\sin(1/x)+e^x$ and $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$? You can't control what happens near $0$ with your conditions, so you're going to get a lot of trivial counterexamples. (...also, the condition about differences doesn't affect anything; if I can extend $f$ smoothly, I'll just set $g(x)=f(x)-e^x$)